# My number of impression on Admob is different from the number of screen views on google analytics

Tags: android, admob

I have the fill rate close to 100% always and I see the ads displaying on my app all the time. I want to know if Google analytic calculates different from admob? I always see the analytic having more screen views than the number of impression on admob.

Answer (score 1):

They are almost certainly going to be different.

You get one screen view each time someone navigates to a page.

You get one ad impression each time an ad is shown. Typically this will be multiple times per screen view.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they are different for me too, but they shouldn't. If you display a banner on a search results (100% of the time), your number should be matching since the ad is displayed everytime the screen is viewed (we have no specific conditions). The only way I could see this problem is if the banner is really slow to display and therefore a new search would be done before the impression is counted.. but that would I guess be reflected by the "Fill rates". If the init of the banner is done but the impression is never counted it would be reflected.

In my case I have less than the half of the Impressions in AdMob compared to the Screen Views in GA.

Let's hope these additional informations helps someone figure out the reason behind it.
Thanks